# How can I package the libusbK driver on Windows 10 for redistribution?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, distribution

I'm working with a GPS sports logger for which Windows 10 default installs the `usbser.sys` driver. This standard driver does **not** support the [WebUSB](https://wicg.github.io/webusb/) API. For that reason, on my local Windows 10 machine, I successfully use [Zadig](https://zadig.akeo.ie/) (v2.4) to install the [libusbK](http://libusbk.sourceforge.net/UsbK3/index.html) driver.

Because I've open sourced the [WebUsb-mtk code](https://github.com/SkunkSports/webusb-mtk) specific to this GPS sports logger (and other loggers with the MTK 3329 GPS module), I'd like to also distribute this signed driver to other Windows 10 users of similar hardware.

**What are the steps to generate an installation package that correctly disables (?) the existing driver and installs the libusbK driver for my hardware?** (LibUSBK is already signed, so I think the signature is not relevant.)

---

p.s. With Mac OS X, WebUSB for this hardware works out of the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to
[libusbK - Creating Client Installers With InfWizard](http://libusbk.sourceforge.net/UsbK3/usbk_installers.html),
the installer does basically all its operations by using the
[Driver Package Installer (DPInst)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/ff544842%28v=vs.90%29),
which is a standard feature in Windows.

According to
[Using DPInst to Uninstall Driver Packages](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/ff553603%28v=vs.96%29),
the syntax to uninstall a driver is:

```
DPInst.exe /u path-to-inf-file
```

The driver for `usbser.sys` I found in the folder
`C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_dual_usbser.inf_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.17134.1_none_8281fb62ec80df7e`,
so uninstalling it could be by using a command such as:

```
DPInst.exe /u C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_dual_usbser.inf_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.17134.1_none_8281fb62ec80df7e
```

It would of course be better if your installer could verify first that this
file exists, and if not then search for it.

The next step would be to install libusbK using the command:

```
DPInst.exe libusbK.inf
```

Since you have installed libusbK, you should have the `.sys` and the `.inf`
files that belong to it.
You need to have them both in one folder, then invoke DPInst on the `.inf`
file.

(As I don't have these files, this answer is mostly theory.)

Comment: thanks! so the installer is actually just a dos script? Can I uninstall usbser.sys for just this device, and not for potentially all devices?

Comment: It was probably done in the installer via a program, rather than a script, but might be possible from a script. From `usbser.inf` I gather that this is a generic driver that is associated with USB devices in general and doesn't specify device-ids. I don't have the files for libusbK so can't examine them.

Comment: I read a bit more. It seems one way is to use Visual Studio to create a driver package https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/develop/creating-a-driver-package
Also it seems DPInst is now DIFX

Comment: Also it seems that Zadig.exe can create the files necessary to share as a driver install package. I'll keep trying, but many thanks for a push in the right direction.

Comment: DPInst is still there and is used by the libusbK installers, so it still works as well as ever. If made available libusbK.inf/sys I'll compare with usbser.inf.

Comment: [Here is the .inf file](https://pastebin.com/raw/KrA8WEBh). Is that enough to compare?

Comment: Comparing the two files, `usbser.inf` is a modern driver handling the class of USB devices. `libusbK.inf` is an older format from before Windows 8, defining its own device class rather than using newer standards. This is discussed in [one post](https://sourceforge.net/p/libusb/mailman/message/34481429/) from 2015 that advises moving to the new standard, but may hint that Zadig may do additional changes to the registry to make it work. The only way is to test DPInst, and if problems, to capture the registry changes done by Zadig (there are products for that). Better use a VM for testing.

Comment: Any way to get `usbser.inf` to work with [WebUSB](https://github.com/WICG/webusb)? _Or is that another question?_

Comment: I don't know the internals of `usbser` that well, so don't know if that's possible, but I doubt that these two different frameworks can be made to work together. If that was easy, libusbK would have been written that way.

Comment: Yeah, I'm in over my head with this driver thing ;) - check out this reply to my comment on the Github issue regarding windows https://github.com/WICG/webusb/issues/143#issuecomment-440348384

Comment: Good, they are on the right track now.